# 404 error using Traefik as ingress controller on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I deployed a demo applicatio on a k8s cluster, using Traefik as ingress controller.
For reference, this is the deployment file for the application:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache
  labels:
    name: apache
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache
        image: httpd:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-svc
  labels:
    name: apache
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: apache
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apache-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: apache-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

While the traefik service is configured as follows:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: traefik
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: http
      targetPort: http
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
      targetPort: admin
  type: NodePort
```

When I try to connect to the application using: `http://<workerIP>:<AdminNodePort>/test/` it gives me a 404 error. If I change the application service type as NodePort and try to access the application through the NodePort, however, it does work. So the problem is definitely the Ingress Controller.

EDIT:
This is the IngressRoute for traefik dashboard:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-webui-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: PathPrefix(`/`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: traefik
      port: 8080
```

So, looking at the service:

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
monitoring     traefik-ingress-service   NodePort    x.x.x.x      <none>        80:<httpNodePort>/TCP,8080:<AdminNodePort>/TCP
```

Comment: What is `AdminNodePort`? Is that `8080` or something else? Is Traefik configured with an entrypoint on that port? If you connect to the Traefik dashboard, do you see your service?

Comment: @larsks edited the question for clarity. AdminNodePort is the NodePort which route to the 8080. And yes, I can connect to the Traefik dashboard using the AdminNodePort

Answer (score 0):

Try below troubleshooting steps which will help you to resolve your issue:

1.Try adding the annotation `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure`
as mentioned in this [document](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/#on-ingress).

2.If you are using a local environment you need to disable the TLS check in traefik. Add this annotation also `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"`

3.If you use TLS as per this [document](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.2/routing/routers/#tls) you need to use 2 ingressroute.

4.You are using `Traefik v1`, current version is `V2` and it is recommended.

Try the above steps and let me know if the issue still persists.

For more information you can follow the [blog](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2020/04/05/traefik-v2-2-and-kubernetes-ingress/) written by Ralph Soika and also the [git link](https://github.com/traefik-workshops/traefik-workshop).